# Using AngularJS with ASP.NET MVC and WCF REST Services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, angularjs

For a new SPA Web App which will initially have very little user interaction and incrementally will have new features which will require lot of user interaction. This app is targeted for mobile devices. I am using this weird combination of technologies.

1. AngularJS + jQuery Mobile - for Client Side - MVC framework + SPA framework.
2. ASP.NET MVC - Server side MVC Framework - which seems unnecessary.
3. WCF REST Services (from 3rd party) - Do not have any control here, just consuming it. These services returns JSON data. All business logic resides here. Application do not have any feature outside of this.

Once application loaded at client side all service calls will happen from AngularJS to REST Services.

The main role of ASP.NET MVC, is just initial request load only. Even user session is handled between AngularJS and REST services.

But I foreseen eventually application will be complex to handle all the stuff at client side. So looking to push some complex processing which is easy and efficient to get done using ASP.NET MVC and .NET Sandbox. I cannot ask REST Service to do this because as i mentioned it is 3rd party.

In dilemma, 
1. Should i maintain user session on server side as well? 
2. How can i utilize ASP.NET MVC best possible way?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I would recommend to create a proxy layer in your MVC application (Which seems unnecessary to you) and route your reset service call through it. thus you will be able to maintain service call and additionally it will prevent API server from being exposed

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Satpal. From security Perspective this is really good option. But this will introduce one additional internet trip for each call to REST Service and will be slower than direct call to service from browser.

Answer (score 1):

Your dilemma is justified and valid. When I go with angularJs, my big question is , do i need to csthml file or shall i use the html file.

I always go with cshtml, hoping that in future there may be scenario where i may have to leverage the server side capabilities of the mvc.

Currently I am working on the same combination of technologies stated above and with modularity of arranging js codes(angular controllers) i don't see any issues.  I am bit curious on what complexities you would be adding to the contoller as you have stated that all your business logic is done by the third partly controller.

If you are looking for security aspect, I would suggest you to write a custom actionfilter which uses httpmodule to do the custom security handling.

With MVC , sessions should be a **BIG NO** . At lease in my organisation it so.

Comment: Thanks for reply Matt. Third party REST services requires lots of inputs and some processing of data which will happen in future from client side / web server side. I have another question  how can we use chtml and AngularJS together? Also, could you please help understand what could be the problem of maintaining session in MVC(server side) along with client side.

Comment: how can we use chtml and AngularJS together - Same way you are treating any other html file you would read/seen in angularjs tutorials. How are you planning to maintain sessions in client side. Also tell me what details are you planning to keep it in session. With angularjs i feel you wont require to keep the data in session at all. Only thing i can think of is user authenticated details, others can be maintained at the client side or at the cache level